# How to insert an entity with OneToMany relation in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

There is the description how to do this in typeorm official docs https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations. But I can't do the same in NestJS with `Repository` and `insert` method.

I have written these entities (other columns were omitted)

```js
    @Entity()
    export class News {
      @OneToMany(type => NewsImage, image => image.news)
      public images: NewsImage[];
    }
    
    @Entity()
    export class NewsImage {
      @ManyToOne(type => News, news => news.images)
      public news: News;
    }
```

I have tried something like this

```js
    function first() {
      const news = new News();
      const image = new NewsImage();
      news.images = [ image ];
      return from(this.newsRepo.insert(news))
        .pipe(
          switchMap(() => this.imageRepo.insert(image)),
        );
    }
    
    function second() {
      const news = new News();
      const image = new NewsImage();
      image.news = news;
      return from(this.imageRepo.insert(image))
        .pipe(
          switchMap(() => this.newsRepo.insert(news)),
        )
    }
```

It inserts news and image, but image's `newsId` is `null`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check cascade property

```js
@Entity()
export class News {
  @OneToMany(type => NewsImage, image => image.news, { cascade: ['insert', 'update'] })
  public images: NewsImage[];
}
```

Then if you do something like

```js
    let news = {
        images: [{
            date: "",
            etc: ""
        }],
        title: ""
    }
```

If then you call `this.repository.save(news)` it will save the news and the images. And updates too. Check more docs about this on typeorm docs.

Comment: How would you handle removing entities that are not in the images[] array, say for an update where an user removes one image from the array, it still exists in the database but instead of deleting the item typeorm/nestjs tries to set the newsId to null on the image @andressh11

Comment: here is a github issue regarding this : https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1460 .

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `new News()` creates a new entity but does not save it to the database. You first need to `insert` or `.save()` the `news` object and then add it to `image`.

```
async function first() {
  // you can .save() it however you want, the point is it must be saved to the db
  const news = await News.create({ title: 'Async rules the world' }).save()
  const image = new NewsImage()
  image.news = news // now news has an id from the database
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this way, but `.insert` returns `InsertResult` object, not `news` entity. I retrieved `id` from `insertResults` and set `id` to `news`, created image entity with that news and it works!